# Writing a Custom Extension Siddhi

Tags: java, wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have a java program for create a siddhi extension, my code is the next:

```
package co.com.easysol.phisingRestClient;

import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float res = new App().phisingProbability("http://dinas.tomsk.ru/js/index.html?paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/");
        System.out.println("res: " + res);
    }

    public float phisingProbability(String url) {
        float res = 0;
        String e = null;
        try {
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            e = client.target("http://52.37.125.225:3000/phishing").queryParam("url", url).request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                    .get(String.class);

            try (JsonReader jr = Json.createReader(new StringReader(e))) {
                String valor = jr.readObject().getString("result");
                try {
                    res = Float.parseFloat(valor);
                } catch (Exception ex1) {
                    res = 0;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

And My Custom.siddhiext:

```
url=co.com.easysol.phisingRestClient.App
```

In my ExecutionPlan I using the next code:

```
from DSBStream
select custom:url(meta_phr_id_pharming_resume) as porc
insert into conteo;
```

The custom.siddhiext file is in /repository/components/lib, but I have the next error:

```
'url' is neither a function extension nor an aggregated attribute extension in execution plan "ExecutionPlan"
```

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your class does not extend an extension class in Siddhi. Since your requirement is to write a custom function, modify it to extend FunctionExecutor and override the required methods [as in this document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Writing+a+Custom+Function+Extension).

More information on extensions can be [found here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Writing+Extensions+to+Siddhi).

Comment: I have created a custom extension as 'public class RunningTime extends FunctionExecutor { ..... } ' as per the doc you have suggested. After building the jar i have placed it in 'dropin' folder. "sample.siddhiext" file entry is 'RunningTime=com.siddhi.sample.RunningTime'
But while using the I am trying to use this in 'try it' tool I am getting RunningTime is neither a function nor an aggregated attribute. ? where i am doing wrong????

Answer (score 0):

You can use archetype to generate the [custom siddhi extensions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SIDDHIEXTENSIONS/Creating+a+Siddhi+Extension+and+Publishing+in+WSO2+Store) and more over that in your resource name is Custom.siddhiext but when you use you typed as custom please check on that.

Comment: Name should be same